# configure: error: gdal-includes not found

Tags: configure, gdal, sumo, plexe-veins, plexe

I am trying to install plexe-sumo on my mac system, when I run `./configure` I get the following error:

`configure: error: gdal-includes not found.`

I have added the path: `usr/local/Cellar/gdal` to my path and yet I still get this error. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by downloading the complete version of gdal from:
http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks
Gave me hell for a good number of days and even though I may not be using a good deal of the complete version it does offer a fix.